# Full size integral symbol in caption

Tags: captions, amsmath

How to obtain "equation environment's size" for integral sign in caption? The one using inline math mode is too small (see caption):

[image]

I've tried using equation environment inside caption but seems not allowed. Any idea? Is there not an equivalent of `\dfrac` for integral?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[mark=none,black,thick] coordinates {(0, 0) (1, 1)};                                
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$T = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `$\displaystyle T=\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx$`

Comment: :) Why the `\,dx` bit?

Comment: The `\,` spaces the differential a bit; look at quality books and you'll find the small space.